# How to use recyclerview in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, fragment, android-recyclerview

I use Navigation Drawer in my Project
and i want to use recyclerview too
but my problem is when i use Navigation Drawer i should use Fragments too
and i tried to use recyclerview in fragment ,but this error displayed in Logcat

> 06-14 21:56:29.376: E/AndroidRuntime(25109): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dmcoder.newsOfcoc/com.dmcoder.newsOfcoc.activity.ActivityMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference

And I'm sorry , my English is not very good

Answer (score 1):

There is no special hackery magic to use RecyclerView inside Fragment.

This error state that your RecyclerView object is null. You need to properly initialize it with findViewById. If you are using fragment you are doing on in the override of onViewCreated, you are supposed to inflate layout you wish to use.